# How to Upload Large File using Android and WCF service

Tags: c#, android, web-services, wcf

I am trying to upload a large file from an android device I first tried to do it using asmx service but it does not work when trying with big files so I change to WCF service but I am actually getting the same outcome, the server reads all the data and write it on the disk until it has finished reading the complete stream the code for the server I am using is this:

```
   [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method="POST",  BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,UriTemplate = "values/")]
        Service1.Work GetData(Stream file);



public Work GetData(Stream file)
        {

            FileStream targetStream = null;
            Stream sourceStream = file;

            string uploadFolder = @"path";



            using (targetStream
                = new FileStream(uploadFolder, FileMode.Create,
                                  FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                //read from the input stream in 65000 byte chunks

                const int bufferLen = 6500;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLen];
                int count = 0;
                while ((count = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen)) > 0)
                {
                    // save to output stream
                    targetStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
                targetStream.Close();
                sourceStream.Close();
            }



            Work w = new Work();
            w.status = "201 "  ;

            return w;
        }
```

I am also using the following code from android to post the info to server:

```
@Multipart
@POST("/values/")
void uploadMediaFile(@Part("description") string des,@Part("id") string id,@Part("file") TypedFile file,CallBack<ApiResponse> cb) throws RetrofitError
```

What I wanted is to have a file on server and start writing it by chunks as soon as the retrofit call comes from android, I have tried many stuff and have not been able to do it here is my config file perhaps it helps.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2000000"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>

      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="transferconfig" sendTimeout="00:25:00" closeTimeout="00:25:23"

          maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000000"          
          maxBufferSize="65536"  transferMode="StreamedResponse"  >

          <security mode="None"> 
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"
                    proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />

          </security>

        </binding>

      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Default" name="UploadFile.Service1">
        <endpoint bindingConfiguration="transferconfig"  behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="UploadFile.IService1"/>

      </service>
    </services> 
    <behaviors>


      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

      <serviceBehaviors>  
        <behavior name="Default">
  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />         
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: ' the server reads all the data and write it on the disk until it has finished reading the complete stream the'. Is that a sentence? Anyhow that approch looks ok. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Yes. When the server gets a large file it stuck before It write it to the disk and takes a long period of time to get the response to my android device, I am looking for a way to as soon as the data is getting in the server it begins to create the file and release memory then, pulling more data and append it to the already created file... any Idea on how achieve this?